# Do I need to delete local variables used in a callback in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Admittedly this stems from my lack of deep understanding of closures.  I found myself with a memory leak and am wondering if this bit of code has anything to do with it.  There does not seem to be a destructor I can manually call in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) for these typed arrays:

```
  myMethod: function() {
    // Create a new array on the heap
    var someData = new Uint8Array(32);
    someData[0] = 1;
    someData[1] = 2;
    ...

    transferSomeData(someData.buffer, function(succeeded) {
      // Dispose of the array
      someData = []; // HOW TO DELETE?
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to delete them. When the callback function exits, the values will become garbage because they aren't accessible, and the garbage collector will recover them.